# Show decimal percent type field

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to show a form which has a percent type field that can show values like 3.03% for exemple. But it seems to be rounding to integers, e.g 3% in this case.

Entity field :

```
    /**
     * @var float
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $penaltyRate;
```

Form builder :

```
...
->add('penaltyRate', PercentType::class, ['label' => 'create.form.penalty'])
```

Is this a limitation of percentType and should I just use another type and add manually the '%' indicator ?

**EDIT**

For future googler, while @Emanuel Oster was right for just pointing to the official symfony documentation, as it wasn't obvious for me the first time I read it here is an example if you want to allow two decimals :

Form builder :

```
    ...
    ->add('penaltyRate', PercentType::class, [
      'label' => 'create.form.penalty',
      'scale' => 2
    ])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the symfony [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/percent.html#scale):

> scale
>
> type: integer default: 0
>
> By default, the input numbers are rounded. To allow for more decimal
>   places, use this option.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
->add('penaltyRate', PercentType::class,[
                'label_format' => 'penaltyRate',
                'scale'=>1, // or 'scale'=>2
                'type'=>'integer'

            ])
```